# Debian, closing lid, want hibernate instead of suspend

Tags: debian, suspend, hibernate

How do you change the settings about the action triggered by the laptop lid closing?

At
`/etc/systemd/logind.conf`
I changed
`#HandleLidSwitch=suspend`
to
`HandleLidSwitch=hibernate`
but it had no effect.

I also tried to change the settings at `gnome-tweak-tool`, but the tool won't let me set anything but suspend as the action triggered by the lid close.

I know that this computer can hibernate. I have run `rtcwake -m disk`.

Comment: Make sure `LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=yes` is not commented either.